# Responsive images in JSP

Tags: css, jsp, responsive

My company has an old JSP page that we are trying to make responsive. As I am going through the templates that our UX team sent us and attempting to implement them, I am learning responsive design at the same time.  I have tried to implement an HTML/CSS responsive images tip whereby the HTML

```
<img srcset="examples/images/image-384.jpg 1x, 
             examples/images/image-768.jpg 2x">
```

and the CSS

```
.img {
  background-image: url(examples/images/image-384.jpg); 
}
@media 
  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
  (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
  .img {
    background-image: url(examples/images/image-768.jpg);
  }
}
```

However, I am finding that this solution doesn't work so well for my application but I haven't found any other tips.

Here's where I am at in the JSP:

```
<%-- <img class="formbackground"                          
srcset="resources/images/Group5209<%=staticAssetsVersionInfoIMAGES%>.jpg 1x,
resources/images/Group5209@2x<%=staticAssetsVersionInfoIMAGES%>.png 2x,
resources/images/Group5209@3x<%=staticAssetsVersionInfoIMAGES%>.png 3x"/> --%>
```

and the CSS:

```
.formbackground{background: url(../images/Group5209@3x.png);

@media (min-width:682px) { 
.formbackground{
        background: url(../images/Group5209.jpg);
    }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    .formbackground{
        background: url(../images/Group5209@2x.png);
    }
}
```

NOTE:  The `<%=staticAssetsVersionInfoIMAGES%>` tag is to help with our asset versioning so that all of our resources are picked up on a content caching system if they ever change.. otherwise, the content cache takes a few hours to catch up.

Can anyone offer any tips to get the images to swap when the page is loaded or resized to a different width?

Comment: Here is what i have been looking at recently - https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/133-figuring-responsive-images/ - Also `srcset` will only work on newer browsers. It looks like you are trying to merge 2 methods into one.

Comment: Here is the codepen for the `srcset` option: - https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/reFLJ

Comment: Hmmm.  I'll take a look at that... In the meantime, the source of the tip i got was from the same site:  https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/  However it seems as thought it's a newer solution that doesn't require JS like the option that you linked to.

Comment: What I sent you is the same as what you replied with. The javascript is there to show you the size of the view port. Its not there to change the images. That is being handled by the browser using `srcset`

Comment: I realized another way to accomplish what i was trying to do... I feel like a bonehead.  I'm using media queries to display a background by pulling the images dynamically as the page is resized.  I'll try to post the solution later.

Comment: actually, due to IE compatibility, I had to use the solution that you pointed out... otherwise i was using media queries and then using `background: url(../images/file.png);` to swap between images in CSS.  the problem was that I can't do that _and_ set `<%=staticAssetsVersionInfoIMAGES%>` so that the images are picked up by our content cache system.  Sorry for my confusion.